# Ubuntu 17.04- can't find pigpiod

Tags: pigpio

On a non Raspberry Pi (just an ordinary laptop, installed with 17.04) - I'm trying to run a Python script to control Pi's Remote GPIO, with no success.

`pigpio` module is installed as ordered in [pigpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/).Installation was OK, and files are present designated directory.

When trying to load pigpio's daemon - `sudo pigpiod`, an error message recieved saying "file not found".

This is the first time I'm trying to use this daemon on a non RPi - perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

```
guy@LG-LAPTOP:~$ sudo pigpiod
[sudo] password for guy: 
sudo: pigpiod: command not found
guy@LG-LAPTOP:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pigpio daemon will only run on a Raspberry Pi.

You can connect to the daemon from a laptop to control the GPIO of the Raspberry Pi, e.g. via a Python script or C program.

Comment: hi, it says "command not found", why?

Comment: @Guy.D I have no idea.  What command?  Where are you running that command?

Comment: @joan- in the text of the question, there is an output. It was ran on PC using ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Yes, and what does my answer say?

Comment: from what I(!) understand from that output is `pigpiod` file/command , is not found. If I'm right- why is that ? it was installed properly.

Comment: Let me sharpen my question a bit: I have 3 RPis controlled by a Python script. On all RPis `pigpiod` run in order to be controlled remptely.
Uptill now, one of the RPis, used to run the control script. All worked OK untill I tried to run that script on PC. Did you mean that on PC `pigpiod` **is not needed**, in order to control RPis ?

Comment: That is correct.  On a non-Pi just run a Python script with `import pigpio` and open the remote Pi with `pi = pigpio.pi("remote_host_name_or_IP_address")`  or use the environment variable `PIGPIO_ADDR=remote_host_name_or_IP_address`

Comment: I see, so the script can be exactly the same when rans on Pi / PC. THNX!